# Distributing 2x6 Different Balls into 4 Boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

> $6$ identical white and $6$ identical red balls will be distributed into $4$ distinguishable boxes. What is the probability that exactly two boxes will be empty?

This is the question I want to solve, I have read the Stars and Bars Method and counted the number of chosen event ($2$ boxes will be empty) as $C(4,2) \cdot C(7,2) \cdot C(7,2)$. Is that part correct? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Is it so that by this distribution for every ball the boxes have equal probability to be selected as the box that contains that ball? And what is the relevance of colors here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wrong.

First part where you did C(4,2) is right. But for second part formulae is C(n-1,b-1) = C(5,1) = 5

This is because both the chosen boxes should contain atleast 1 ball.

This can also be seen manually as possible combination on 6 identicall balls in different boxes is 5

(1,5);(2,4);(3,3);(4,2);(5,1)

So final answer is C(4,2)*5*5 = 150

Comment: thank you for the answer. Is the sample space (without any restrictions) C(9,3)^2 ?

Comment: By without any restriction, you mean that we have 2 boxes and non empty box condition is not there. Right?

Comment: 6 identical white and 6 identical red balls will be distributed into 4 distinguishable boxes.So we have 4.

Comment: Here is a link which covers all the cass. Go through it once.http://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/permutations_combinations_imp7.php

Answer (score 1):

It should be $C(7,1)$, because there is only one bar when you distribute between two boxes. In addition, you're including the cases where three of the boxes are empty in your count, and each of those cases is counted multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The number of distinct ways of distributing 6 balls into 4 boxes, is, according to Bars and Stars:

$$\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{9}{3}=84$$

This would apply separetely to the $6$ white balls as well as to the $6$ red ones. Then it follows that there are $84^2=7056$ ways of distributing the $12$ balls into the $4$ boxes.

On the other hand, the favourable cases are computed as follows:

Suppose we want to leave out boxes $1$ and $2$. Then, analogous to what we did above, the number of distinct ways of putting the $12$ balls into boxes $3$ and $4$ is:
$$\binom{6+2-1}{2-1}^2=7^2=49$$

As pointed by Sagar Chand, we are overcounting, since we don't want the cases where the box $3$ or $4$ are empty. But this is easily fixable, since there are only two such cases: All balls in the $4$ or all balls in the $3$.

Then there are $49-2=47$ favourable cases where the box $1$ and $2$ are empty and the $3$ and $4$ are not. This applies to the $\binom{4}{2}=6$ pairs of boxes we can choose to be empty. Then, the total favourable cases for 2 empty boxes is $47\cdot6=282$.
It follows that the probability of having two empty boxes is $$\dfrac{282}{7056} \sim 0.04=4 \%$$